# Why do I need to support sticky sessions in Jetty when storing in data store?

Tags: session, jetty

I'm looking to store sessions in an external data store instead of in memory. I want to do this in order to have session data available to all my Jetty server instances.

So I read the Jetty docs:

[Session Clustering with a Database](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-clustering-jdbc.html)

[Session Clustering with MongoDB](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/session-clustering-mongodb.html)

Both docs have the following statement:

> The persistent session mechanism works in conjunction with a load balancer that supports stickiness.

My question is - why do I need stickiness in this mechanism? The whole point is to allow any server in the cluster serve any request because the session data is stored externally.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the servlet specification does not provide any transactional semantics around sessions. Thus, unless your sessions are sticky its possible for concurrent requests involving the same session to go to multiple servers and produce inconsistent results, depending on the interleaving of the writes. If your sessions are read-mostly you may get away with non-sticky sessions, although you may find that sessions time out a little sooner or a little later than you'd expect, due to having multiple servers trying to manage the same session.